# Block hosts with Capybara selenium

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

Is there a way to block domains using the `selenium` web driver? I know you can use `page.driver.browser.url_blacklist` for the `webkit` driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no black/whitelist support in the selenium driver, however if you use the puffing-billy gem it works with the selenium to autoconfigure a proxy that allows for black or whitelisting urls